# Daily calorie intake and body weight dataset

Tags: data-request, medical

I'm devising a mathematical method to filter out weight fluctuations from daily weight measurements. To validate the method, I would require a dataset containing daily weight measurements and calorie intake information from a population. Ideally, the dataset would also include body fat measurements (any of these would be helpful: bioimpedance, skinfold caliper, underwater weighing, DEXA, BodPod, etc.)

Is anyone aware of an open dataset containing such information?

Comment: One study that immediately springs to mind is the [Minnesota Starvation Study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesota_Starvation_Experiment).